# Why is crawl database read-heavy and link database write-heavy?

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, search, database

As per [Technet specifications](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc678868.aspx) for the crawl database:

> Read/write characteristics: Read heavy.

Wouldn't crawling require rather write operations than read?

On the other hand for the link database:

> Read/write characteristics: Write heavy during content processing.

Once the links are created (write operation) wouldn't reading them (users browsing, searching etc.) occur more frequently than writing new ones?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Grisha,

I will try to give you a brief definitions of the concepts in order to help you to build a better overview about the search components.

**Crawling** is simply a process of gathering documents from various sources/repositories, making sure they obey by various rules and sending them off for further processing to the Content Processing Component.

**Read** during Gathering.
**Write** towards Content Processing Component.
You can follow the counters of **mssdmn.exe** process on the task manger performance monitor.

**Content Processing** Component:

The content processing component processes crawled items and sends these items to the index component. The content processing component performs operations such as document parsing and property mapping. It also performs linguistics processing such as language detection and entity extraction. The component transforms crawled items into artifacts that are included in the search index. The content processing component also writes information about links and URLs to the link database.

You can follow the counters and activity of **noderunner.exe** (PID- Task Manager) process associated to **NodeRunnerContent** (PID - ULS).
The **Reading** is lower since it has the info already and it is mainly busy **writing** properties in to the indexer.

**Users browsing** is another different process associated to **w3wp.exe** 
SharePoint **Search** is a combination of **NodeRunnerQuery** and **NodeRunner**